# Redisson is spamming redis

Tags: java, redis, redisson

Spring boot app using hibernate and redis as cache.
Problem is - redis have up-to 80K op/sec when app get 250 rps.
here is spring configuration for redis (from https://redisson.org/glossary/spring-cache.html)

```
@Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedissonClient redissonClient) {
            return new RedissonSpringCacheManager(redissonClient) {
                @Override
                public Cache getCache(String cacheName) {
                    Cache cache = super.getCache(cacheName);
                    return new RedisCacheWrapper(cache);
                }

                @Override
                protected CacheConfig createDefaultConfig() {
                    CacheConfig cacheConfig = new CacheConfig(ttl, maxIdleTime);
                    cacheConfig.setMaxSize(maxSize);
                    return cacheConfig;
                }
            };
    }
```

hibernate just @Cache annotation on cache required entity

```
@Cache(region = HIBERNATE_MY_REGION, usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class MyEntity{
...
} 
and next libs
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson-hibernate-53</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

i checked app in local and opening some pages (no any hard work under the hood, just getting by id and external id) and there are profiling from redisinsignt

[image: profiling for 9 sec]

For now moved redis to cluster mode and up multiple slave redis modes to be able handle so many op/sec.

Comment: I think any technology or tool is used to solve problems. Maybe they are not very suitable in some scenarios, but it does not mean that they are not good. After all, they were born because they can solve some problems.In my opinion, it is better to choose the right tool than the trendy tool

Comment: I hope redisson is suitable here but i doing something wrong. I keep option to switch to jedis or some another java client to redis but in first trying to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

That might be caused by cleanup process. Which can be tuned by increasing https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration#mincleanupdelay and https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration#cleanupkeysamount settings